# Xcode 7.3. Your account already has has a valid destribution certificate and than an App Id is not available

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7.3

After update to Xcode 7.3 I am getting errors while trying to submit my app on beta testing via TestFlight. It is very strange because I have managed to submit more than ten build with the same App Id.

I am making an archive and tap on Upload to App Store
As the result I am getting and error:

"You account already has a valid iOS Distribution certificate. You have a valid iOS Distribution certificate in the Member Center, but it is not installed locally. If your signing identity is installed on another Mac, you can export a developer profile on that Mac and import it on this Mac. You can also reset your current certificate."

If I tap cancel on this warning message, I get the new one:

"Xcode attempted to locate or generate matching signing assets and failed to do so because of the following issues. An App ID with identifier 'com.abc.Defg' is not available. Please enter a different string".

Answer (score 0):

I have the same thing.

Where are different ways to solve your problem :

1.To install certificate again from member center to your mac.

2.To install one new certificate and news parameters(app_id, and others) to your application.

I didn't find why it's happening now, but if I can help you-great!

Sorry for my english, GoodLuck!

Answer (score 0):

Ruslan, follow the steps below:

1. Go to your Xcode > Preferences
2. Make sure you're on 'Accounts' tab
3. Click your apple id
4. Click 'View Details' and inside 'Provisioning Profiles',
   if you already have profiles, select all and delete them. Restart your Xcode and come back to this state (following above steps) and click 'Download all'.

**If you don't have any profiles in step 4, just click 'Download all'

After this, try again!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this one issue is only for Xcode 7.3. If you install later version, for now only beta GM is available, you will cope with such an task.